# Ruby - update instance variable from inside a block

Tags: ruby-2.0, pry

How do you update an instance variable from inside a block?

E.g.

```
def initialize_people(people)
    people.each do |person|
        person = "Bob" if person.nil?
    end 
end

@first = "Adam"
@second = "Eve"
@third = nil

people = [@first, @second, @third]
initialize_people(people)       
puts people

# outputs 
# Adam
# Eve

# would like it to output
# Adam
# Eve
# Bob
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression:

```
people.each |person|
```

Defines `person` locally to the loop. So, all your loop did is set the locally scoped `person` to `Bob` when it was found to be `nil`. You could do something like this:

```
def initialize_people(people)
    people.each_with_index do |person, i|
        people[i] = "Bob" if person.nil?
    end 
end
```

Or shorter:

```
i = people.find_index(nil)
people[i] = "Bob" if i
```